# In asymptote, how to draw the projection of point P down the respective coordinate systems x'O'y' and x''O''y''

Tags: asymptote

I want to plot the projection of point P down the respective coordinate systems x'O'y' (blue) and x''O''y'' (green).

I did the same as in the xOy coordinate system but got the error as shown in the figure.

My code

```
size(8cm,0);
import geometry;

coordsys R=defaultcoordsys;
show("O",R);

coordsys Rp=cartesiansystem((0.5,0.5), i=(0.35,0.35), j=(-0.35,0.35));
show("O'", "$\vec{\imath'}$", "$\vec{\jmath'}$", Rp, ipen=blue);//, xpen=invisible);

coordsys Rpp=cartesiansystem((-1,-0.5),
                                      i=rotate(-90)*(0.35,0.35),
                                      j=rotate(-90)*(-0.35,0.35));
show("O''", "$\vec{\imath''}$", "$\vec{\jmath''}$", Rpp, ipen=green);//, xpen=invisible);

pair m=(1,1),
xm=(m.x,0),
ym=(0,m.y),
O=(0,0)
;

real r=5;
dot("",point(R,m),red);
markrightangle(size=r,point(R,xm),O,point(R,ym),red);

dot("",point(Rp,m),blue);
markrightangle(size=r,point(Rp,xm),point(Rp,O),point(Rp,ym),blue);

point M=m;
dot("",point(Rpp,M),green);
markrightangle(size=r,point(Rpp,xm),point(Rpp,O),point(Rpp,ym),green);

pair p=(0.75,-0.75);
point P=point(R,p),
PR=P,
xPR=(point(R,p).x,0),
yPR=(0,point(R,p).y),
PRp=point(Rp,p),
xPRp=(point(Rp,p).x,0),
yPRp=(0,point(Rp,p).y),
PRpp=point(Rpp,p),
xPRpp=(point(Rpp,p).x,0),
yPRpp=(0,point(Rpp,p).y)
;

dot("$P$",P,2E,4mm+red);
dot("$P'$",point(Rp,p/Rp),2S,3mm+blue);
dot("$P''$",changecoordsys(Rpp,P),2W,1.5mm+green);

draw(xPR--PR--yPR,dashed+red);
//draw(xPRp--PRp--yPRp,dashed+blue);
//draw(xPRpp--PRpp--yPRpp,dashed+green);

pair px[]={xPR,yPR};
string sx[]={"$x_\mathrm{PO}$","$y_\mathrm{PO}$"};
int gx[]={90,180};
for(int ii=0; ii<px.length;++ii )dot(sx[ii],px[ii],dir(gx[ii]),Fill(white));

addMargins(1cm,1cm);
```

[image]
Help me, please!

Answer (score 1):

Please find two solutions. The first one uses `changecoordsys` to recover the `x` and `y` coordinates of the point `P` in the `Rp` system coordinates. The second one uses an orthogonal projection.

```
size(8cm,0);
import geometry;

coordsys R=defaultcoordsys;
show("O",R);

coordsys Rp=cartesiansystem((0.5,0.5), i=(0.35,0.35), j=(-0.35,0.35));
show("O'", "$\vec{\imath'}$", "$\vec{\jmath'}$", Rp, ipen=blue);//, xpen=invisible);

coordsys Rpp=cartesiansystem((-1,-0.5),
                             i=rotate(-90)*(0.35,0.35),
                             j=rotate(-90)*(-0.35,0.35));
show("O''", "$\vec{\imath''}$", "$\vec{\jmath''}$", Rpp, ipen=green);//, xpen=invisible);

pair m=(1,1),
xm=(m.x,0),
ym=(0,m.y),
O=(0,0)
  ;

real r=5;
dot("",point(R,m),red);
markrightangle(size=r,point(R,xm),O,point(R,ym),red);

dot("",point(Rp,m),blue);
markrightangle(size=r,point(Rp,xm),point(Rp,O),point(Rp,ym),blue);

point M=m;
dot("",point(Rpp,M),green);
markrightangle(size=r,point(Rpp,xm),point(Rpp,O),point(Rpp,ym),green);

pair p=(0.75,-0.75);
point P=point(R,p);
point xPR=(point(R,p).x,0);
point yPR=(0,point(R,p).y);
// 1st solution 
point zPRp=changecoordsys(Rp,P);
point xPRp=point(Rp,(zPRp.x,0));
point yPRp=point(Rp,(0,zPRp.y));
// 2nd solution
point xPRpp=projection(Rpp.O,Rpp.O+Rpp.i)*P;
point yPRpp=projection(Rpp.O,Rpp.O+Rpp.j)*P;


dot("$P$",P,2E,4mm+red);
dot("$P'$",point(Rp,p/Rp),2S,3mm+blue);
dot("$P''$",changecoordsys(Rpp,P),2W,1.5mm+green);

draw(xPR--P--yPR,dashed+red);
draw(xPRp--P--yPRp,dashed+blue);
draw(xPRpp--P--yPRpp,dashed+green);

pair px[]={xPR,yPR};
string sx[]={"$x_\mathrm{PO}$","$y_\mathrm{PO}$"};
int gx[]={90,180};
for(int ii=0; ii<px.length;++ii )dot(sx[ii],px[ii],dir(gx[ii]),Fill(white));


addMargins(1cm,1cm);
```

and the result

[image]

Comment: O.G., thank you so much!